# Getting the wanted value across two columns in R

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to find a way to get a specific ID as a new column.

My data.frame looks like this below:

```
V1 V2 
A B
C A
D A
A E
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
V1 V2 V3 
A B B 
C A C 
D A D 
A E E
```

Essentially, a new column that isn't A, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I've made a minor edit to remove some of the pleasantries from your question. While the sentiment is appreciated, Stack Overflow/Exchange is a little different from a forum in that we discourage that to keep questions and answers more brief and readable for information seekers. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use an `ifelse`

```
df1$V3 <- with(df1, ifelse(V1 == 'A', V2, V1))
df1
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  A  B  B
#2  C  A  C
#3  D  A  D
#4  A  E  E
```

---

Or as @markus mentioned

```
with(df1, replace(V1, V1 == "A", V2[V1 == "A"]))
```

---

Or another option is to create a row/column index with `max.col` and then extract the values based on the index

```
df1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), max.col(df1 != 'A'))]
#[1] "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "C", "D", "A"), V2 = c("B", "A", "A", 
"E")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option (would be slow when with many rows)

```
df$V3 <- apply(df,1,setdiff,"A")
```

such that

```
> df
  V1 V2 V3
1  A  B  B
2  C  A  C
3  E  A  E
4  A  D  D
```